# How to test if two pandas categorical Series differ only by the category labels

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

Suppose I have two categorical `pandas.Series` like so:

```
> series_1 = pandas.Categorical(
    ["A", "B", "C", "A", "C"],
    categories=["A", "B", "C"]
)

> series_2 = pandas.Categorical(
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 3],
    categories=[1, 3, 2]
)
```

So, the two series have the exact same informational content but differ only by how the categories were labeled. My goal is to test this very fast because I have a data frame with hundreds of such columns.

What I did so far was to calculate a contingency table with `pandas.crosstab` and check if it is a diagonal matrix (with `np.diag(cont_table).sum() == cont_table.sum()`, which is not perfect).

I could simply convert the labels into integers and always use the order of the first appearance to guarantee that corresponding labels would be assigned to the same integer, but I feel that this is such a basic task that surely pandas already have some way of doing this.

Hence the question is: is there a fast, simple way of doing this check with a few calls to pandas methods?

---

EDIT:

Changed to a different example that demonstrates the difficulty of the task more clearly, since some of the answers worked for the previous example but don't solve the general problem. Notice that I can't generally trust that the categories in the two series will be correctly paired in the same order of the corresponding labels.

In [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rcalsaverini/8d793d3059dbc6f44c0635ad3717bac3) there is a code that generates random instances of this problem to test eventual solutions. The code is simply:

1. generates two numpy arrays with the same structure but different labels
2. labels create two series and call the `.astype('category')` method.

It routinely generates cases where the categories are not in order.

Comment: Are you asking if pandas has a way to map country codes to country names? If not, do you have such a mapping? I presume that the order of the series is not guaranteed to match, i.e. there can be instances where say the 3rd entry in one series is UK but the corresponding 3rd entry in the other series is *not* United Kingdom

Comment: Nope. That was only an example. My general question is how do I check that two categorical series are really different in their structure and not simply have their labels in exact same structure but only renamed.

Comment: You should be able to test your code with this gist: https://gist.github.com/rcalsaverini/8d793d3059dbc6f44c0635ad3717bac3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after banging my head against the documentation for a while it turns out that I can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

def compare_categorical_series():
    values_1, *_ = pd.factorize(feature_1)
    values_2, *_ = pd.factorize(feature_2)
    return np.all(values_1 == values_2)
```

The `factorize` function transforms every entry into an integer value, using the same integer for equal. Of course, this is not enough, it also needs to do that in the always in the same order, irrespectively of the actual labels.

Although this behavior is **not documented** in the pandas documentation as is, after extensive testing it seems that this is the behavior. It seems the integers are attributed in the order that the labels appear in the series, which would be enough to guarantee the behavior needed for this application.

But since this behavior is not documented, it might change in the future, so it's good to have test cases in place to detect a possible change in behavior.

Answer (score -1):

If you are confident that the ordering of the categories is the same (as in this example), you could just do:

```
series_match = (series_1 == series_2).all()
// True for this example
```

Comment: I can't guarantee the ordering because the series are read from CSV files and converted to categorical labels later. I can't control the ordering, so it must be robust against that.

Comment: I updated the example to make it more clear that I can't trust the order of the categories. I was able to randomly produce several examples that naturally produce situations like this with the code in the gist mentioned in the question.